# Identically configured checkbox form elements produce identical HTML code but display differently

Tags: php, forms, checkbox, zend-framework

[image: Screenshot of the issue]I'm simplifying my site's Registration page to make it quicker and easier for new users to register for a new user account.

I'm using Zend and PHP and I have a really strange problem:

- 4 checkboxes, created identically
- The first two display fine
- The second two display in a broken format (described below)

Tried the following:

- Moving the working checkboxes around the page - They continue to work.
- Moving the broken checkboxes around the page - They continue to fail.
- Refreshing browser cache.
- Restarted apache
- Doing a text comparison to ensure that all code is identical.

PHP form definition:

```
    $this->addElement('checkbox','user_working1',array(
        'label'=>'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;I am working1',
        "class"      => "form-control hoverToolTip",
        "required"   => false,
    ));



    $this->addElement('checkbox','user_working2',array(
        'label'=>'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;I am working2',
        "class"      => "form-control hoverToolTip",
        "required"   => false,
    ));


    $this->addElement('checkbox','user_broken3',array(
        'label'=>'I am broken3',
        "class"      => "form-control hoverToolTip",
        "required"   => false,
    ));


    $this->addElement('checkbox','user_broken4',array(
        'label'=>'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;I am broken4',
        "class"      => "form-control hoverToolTip",
        "required"   => false,          
    ));
```

PHP view:

```
<div class="row margin-0">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
        <div class="">
            <h4 class="form-signin-heading">
                Professional Profile&nbsp; <i class="fa fa-briefcase"></i>
            </h4>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-9">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="input-group form-group">
                        <?php echo $this->form->user_working1?> 
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="input-group form-group"> 
                        <?php echo $this->form->user_working2?> 
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row margin-0">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
        <div class="">
            <h4 class="form-signin-heading">
                Professional Profile&nbsp; <i class="fa fa-briefcase"></i>
            </h4>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-9">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="input-group form-group">
                        <?php echo $this->form->user_broken3?> 
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="input-group form-group"> 
                        <?php echo $this->form->user_broken4?> 
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

HTML output:

```html
    <div class="row margin-0">
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
            <div class="">
                <h4 class="form-signin-heading">
                    Professional Profile&nbsp; <i class="fa fa-briefcase"></i>
                </h4>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-9">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="input-group form-group">
                            <div class=" form-group "><label for="user_working1" class="optional">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;I am working1</label>

<input type="hidden" name="user_working1" value="0"><input type="checkbox" name="user_working1" id="user_working1" value="1" class="form-control hoverToolTip"></div> 
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="input-group form-group"> 
                            <div class=" form-group "><label for="user_working2" class="optional">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;I am working2</label>

<input type="hidden" name="user_working2" value="0"><input type="checkbox" name="user_working2" id="user_working2" value="1" class="form-control hoverToolTip"></div> 
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



    <div class="row margin-0">
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
            <div class="">
                <h4 class="form-signin-heading">
                    Professional Profile&nbsp; <i class="fa fa-briefcase"></i>
                </h4>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-9">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="input-group form-group">
                            <div class=" form-group "><label for="user_broken3" class="optional">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;I am broken3</label>

<input type="hidden" name="user_broken3" value="0"><input type="checkbox" name="user_broken3" id="user_broken3" value="1" class="form-control hoverToolTip"></div> 
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="input-group form-group"> 
                            <div class=" form-group "><label for="user_broken4" class="optional">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;I am broken4</label>

<input type="hidden" name="user_broken4" value="0"><input type="checkbox" name="user_broken4" id="user_broken4" value="1" class="form-control hoverToolTip"></div> 
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```css
.input-group .form-control:last-child, .input-group-addon:last-child, .input-group-btn:last-child > .btn, .input-group-btn:last-child > .dropdown-toggle, .input-group-btn:first-child > .btn:not(:first-child) {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
}
.input-group-addon, .input-group-btn, .input-group .form-control {
    display: table-cell;
}
.input-group .form-control {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
input[type="radio"], input[type="checkbox"] {
    margin: 4px 0 0;
    margin-top: 1px \9;
    line-height: normal;
}
input[type="checkbox"], input[type="radio"] {
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.form-control {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 34px;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.428571429;
    color: #555555;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
    -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out 0.15s, box-shadow ease-in-out 0.15s;
    transition: border-color ease-in-out 0.15s, box-shadow ease-in-out 0.15s;
}
input, button, select, textarea {
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
    line-height: inherit;
}
button, input {
    line-height: normal;
}
button, input, select, textarea {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: 100%;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
user agent stylesheet
input[type="checkbox" i] {
    margin: 3px 3px 3px 4px;
}
user agent stylesheet
input[type="checkbox" i] {
    -webkit-appearance: checkbox;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
user agent stylesheet
input[type="checkbox" i] {
    background-color: initial;
    cursor: default;
    margin: 3px 0.5ex;
    padding: initial;
    border: initial;
}
user agent stylesheet
input {
    padding: 1px 0px;
}
user agent stylesheet
input {
    -webkit-appearance: textfield;
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
    cursor: text;
    padding: 1px;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: inset;
    border-color: initial;
    border-image: initial;
}
user agent stylesheet
input {
    text-rendering: auto;
    color: initial;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    word-spacing: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    text-indent: 0px;
    text-shadow: none;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: start;
    margin: 0em;
    font: 400 13.3333px Arial;
}
user agent stylesheet
input {
    -webkit-writing-mode: horizontal-tb !important;
}
.input-group {
    position: relative;
    display: table;
    border-collapse: separate;
}
body {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #323232;
}
body {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.428571429;
    color: #333333;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
html {
    font-size: 62.5%;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
html {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
user agent stylesheet
html {
    color: -internal-root-color;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
```

Expected results:

- All checkboxes displayed on the left hand side, followed by label on the right

Actual results:

- 2 checkboxes working as expected
- 2 broken checkboxes display with the Label above checkbox and the Checkbox centered in the middle of a text box

Comment: It sounds like a CSS-styling issue. Right-click on the checkbox, label elements and containing DIV in your browser window and compare the 'computed' styles of the working VS non-working checkboxes. Possible CSS style to compare is 'display'.. if the labels are on their own line, they might be set to `display: block`

Comment: This uses Bootstrap? If I test your HTML I get this: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/KIKO_Software/p9v2Lu61) Using `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;` is never a good way to align text... I would start there.

Comment: Yes, sorry I should've mentioned that my site uses bootstrap.

Comment: Removing the spaces (&nbsp;) in the label makes no difference.

Comment: I can't tell, because, as you can see, I get something different when I use your HTML code. You can add your own styles to the fiddle, save it, and show to us what happens.

Comment: I've added an image at the top of the question to demonstrate the symptoms.

Comment: Can you post the CSS for this page?

Comment: That is indeed what I got from the text in your question. But we cannot work with an image. As Ryan already concluded 15 minitues ago, this must be a CSS style issue. I agree with that. You can check the styles yourself, or let us help you, but we would need to know what styles you have used: Classes like `optional`.

Comment: I've add the styles to the question.

Comment: I'm still not getting what you have: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/KIKO_Software/p9v2Lu61/4/). I'm sorry, but I have to go, so I won't respond quickly anymore. I did add an extra `}` at the end of your styles.

Comment: I've been able to get all checkboxes to break on JSFiddle so it looks like something within my bootstrap.css.  BTW there are no styles within bootstrap.css for the optional class.

Answer (score 0):

I found some custom CSS which had been written a while ago.
The custom CSS was applying custom styles to the element names!

This is why I couldn't get the broken fields to work and why the working fields kept working.

As you can probably already tell, I'm no CSS expert but I'm going to focus on tidying up my CSS to apply consistent styling to my elements by element type and class and not by element name.